# Undeclared identifier 'trend

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

```
 //@version=5
indicator("Dual SuperTrend", shorttitle="DST", overlay=true)

// Function to calculate SuperTrend
supertrend(src, length, multiplier) =>
    atrValue = ta.atr(length)
    upTrend = src + multiplier * atrValue
    downTrend = src - multiplier * atrValue
    closeValue = close[1]
    trend = closeValue > nz(trend[1]) ? (closeValue > nz(upTrend[1]) ? upTrend : downTrend) : (closeValue < nz(downTrend[1]) ? downTrend : upTrend)
    [trend, closeValue > trend ? color.new(color.green, 0) : color.new(color.red, 0)]

// Fetch daily data using security function
dailyClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)

// Calculate SuperTrend with daily data
[dailyST, dailyColor] = supertrend(dailyClose, 14, 1.0)

// Calculate SuperTrend with chart's timeframe
[chartST, chartColor] = supertrend(close, 14, 1.0)

// Plot SuperTrend on the chart
plot(dailyST, color=dailyColor, title="Daily SuperTrend", linewidth=2)
plot(chartST, color=chartColor, title="Chart SuperTrend", linewidth=2)
```

Hi all, I am new to pine script, above is my code and it throws an exception Undeclared identifier 'trend while compiling on trading view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first declare the variable then use it in an expression. You should use the `:=` operator to assign a new value to an already declared variable.

```
trend = 0.0
trend := closeValue > nz(trend[1]) ? (closeValue > nz(upTrend[1]) ? upTrend : downTrend) : (closeValue < nz(downTrend[1]) ? downTrend : upTrend)
```